# Time Series Analysis vs Linear Regression for Stock Price Prediction

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, predictive-models, finance

I see many online blogs that use Linear Regression to predict future stock price.
I too have done this and my x variable is time elapsed.

But I have been advised this problem is better suited for Time Series problem instead of Linear Regression. I want to understand why and what is the difference between say ARIMA and Linear Regression in the context of predicting future stock prices based on historical data. e.g. date and closing price.

Comment: I see that you do not accept the answer and not ask clarifications, nor give opinions. What do you think?

Answer (score -2):

> I want to understand why and what is the difference between say ARIMA
> and Linear Regression in the context of predicting future stock prices
> based on historical data. e.g. date and closing price.

Usually in financial literature "stock predictability" should be intended as predictability of stock returns, not stock price. Indeed, predict price variations is what is challenging and potentially fruitful.

For (log)price model like ARIMA(p,1,q) are usual, but them imply an ARMA(p,q) for (log)return. So after this passage we can work with ARMA (subclass of ARIMA).

Thsi discussion is related: [Forecasting Prices vs Returns by Deep Learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497877/forecasting-prices-vs-returns-by-deep-learning/497889#497889)

Now, for returns predictability we can consider *linear regression* and *ARMA models* as competitors. It seems me that your question is about that.

In some presentations ARMA can appear as separate concept respect to linear regression. Even the background matters, several machine learners never face ARMA models. However seems me very useful to grasp the connections at first place.

Indeed them are strongly related. Suffice to keep in mind that under usual condition (stationarity, invertibility) an ARMA process can be represented as a pure AR one, pure *autoregressive*. However for parsimony/efficiency reasons ARMA specifications can be better; if MA part is included we move away from usual "OLS regression".

Use past returns as predictors is frequently the first step even for "regressionist". Then we can say that even them performs ARMA models (a subclass of them), sometimes unknowingly.

Moreover both (linear regression and ARMA) can be considered as specifications for *conditional expectation function* (CEF) in linear approximation. (Related: [Regression and the CEF](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484914/regression-and-the-cef/484930#484930))

The main difference between the two is that ARMA models consider only past values of the serie under analysis, while linear regression is more general and permit to consider other variables as predictors.

Finally, in estimation term for ARMA the ML procedure are usual. For linear regression we can use OLS but even procedure as LASSO or RIDGE can be involved.

Comment: It is difficult to see how linear regression of a response against time (as described in the question) might be "strongly related" to or even conflated with ARMA/ARIMA modeling.  This assertion might even be misleading unless the relationship is clearly spelled out.  Could you elaborate on that in your answer?

Comment: I can try, give me some minutes

Comment: I skipped the problem of time trend because it seem me not a core point.

Comment: I think that is the entire point of this question.

Comment: I think not. In stock prediction time trend is not important and the kind of trend managed with ARIMA is not this. However we can wait asker opinion. Eventually i can modify /delete my answer.

Comment: It's not a matter of what you or I might think: the question quite clearly and explicitly states "use Linear Regression to predict future stock price. I too have done this and my x variable is time elapsed."  There's no need to wait to know the OP's opinion!

Comment: I readed this part too. Moreover i firstly readed the title (without time trend). Exactly for this reason I underscored the part of the question I focused on, it seems me the core. Several questions touch more than one point but not all crucial. I think that the asker tell us that it try to use time trend, but the core is elsewhere.

Comment: Seriously not sure what information this post adds to the thread.

Comment: I tried to explain my point better

Comment: @Chris;  what sound you wrong or out of place?